# How to make a list of buttons dynamically and show them in the MainForm in a ListBox or ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new in the WPF.
I want to make the list of buttons from a list of a class say "Buttons" and having two fields (ButtonContent,ButtonID) in the MainForm in WPF.
The idea behind this is that when the MainForm will be loaded then i want to make buttons list dynamically.
The Best Example is already given in the Link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25030/Animating-Interactive-D-Elements-in-a-D-Panel
But i only want to make the equal size buttons stacked horizontally.

How can i do this in WPF? Thank you in advance.

Comment: see about [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [StackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it.  There are some areas here that will need further research on your part, but this will get you started.

First you need your ViewModel.  This is the plain old object.  It exposes the properties and methods that are pertinent to your business.  You mentioned ButtonContent and ButtonID.  Let's assume that both of those are strings for now.  You'll also need a command for your button I assume.

```
public class ButtonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string _content;
   public string Content
   {
      get{ return _content; }
      set{ _content = value; OnPropertyChanged("Content"); }
   }

   // you'll need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged
   // also take a look at RelayCommand

   // here is your command for you're button
   public ICommand ButtonCommand
   {
      get { return new RelayCommand(execute, canExecute); }
   }

   private void execute()
   {
     // my actual command code
   }

   private bool canExecute()
   {
      // this will automatically toggle the enabled state on my button
   }
}
```

You'll have one more view model.  This will be the DataContext of your MainWindow.

```
public class AppViewModel
{
   public ObservableCollection<ButtonViewModel> MyButtons {get; set; }

   public AppViewModel()
   {
      MyButtons = new ObservableCollection<ButtonViewModel>();

      // add some demo data
      MyButtons.Add(new ButtonViewModel() {ButtonContent = "Click Me!"});


   }
}
```

Now you need to implement the view.  In the MainWindow xaml code.  Add your xmlns:local namespace.

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <local:AppViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyButtons}">
   <ListBox.ItemsTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
      <Button Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" Content="{Binding Content}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   <ListBox.ItemsTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Hopefully this can get you started in the right direction.